# indexing error when plotting multiple plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple graphs via subplot. The code "works" but it always gives me an index error that I can't for the life of me figure out.

As a side question, I was wondering if anyone knew how to keep each separate plot the same size. For example, if I added more rows or columns then each plot gets smaller. Thanks.

```
count = 0
n_rows = 2
n_columns = 2
f, axarr = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_columns)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

for column in range(n_cols):
    for row in range(n_rows):
        axarr[row, column].imshow(generate_pattern('block3_conv1', count, size=150))

        count += 1
```

[image]

Error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-7f7ae19e07e9> in <module>()
      7 for column in range(n_cols):
      8     for row in range(n_rows):
----> 9         axarr[row, column].imshow(generate_pattern('block3_conv1', count, size=150))
     10 
     11         count += 1

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

**Code for functions used**

```
def generate_pattern(layer_name, filter_index, size=150):
    # Build a loss function that maximizes the activation
    # of the nth filter of the layer considered.
    layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
    loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])

    # Compute the gradient of the input picture wrt this loss
    grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]

    # Normalization trick: we normalize the gradient
    grads /= (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(grads))) + 1e-5)

    # This function returns the loss and grads given the input picture
    iterate = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])

    # We start from a gray image with some noise
    input_img_data = np.random.random((1, size, size, 3)) * 20 + 128.

    # Run gradient ascent for 40 steps
    step = 1.
    for i in range(40):
        loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
        input_img_data += grads_value * step

    img = input_img_data[0]
    return deprocess_image(img)

def deprocess_image(x):
    x -= x.mean()
    x /= (x.std() + 1e-5)
    x *= 0.1

    x += 0.5
    x = np.clip(x,0,1)

    x *= 255
    x = np.clip(x,0,255).astype('uint8')

    return x
```

Comment: What does the code for your `generate_pattern()` function look like?

Comment: I edited my original question to include 'generate_pattern()'

Comment: That error is almost certainly because you have tried to index `axarr` with two. It can only be indexed with a one or zero as the length is two like `axarr[0,1]` or `axarr[1,1]`. But this is strange because as the code is posted here you would not be indexing with the number two. Did you change the code in the process of posting your question?

Comment: Nope the code I put is the one that gives the error. Though I didnt know that about axarr so thanks for that.

Comment: Okay, because if the error was occurring inside your `generate_pattern` function, then the return would be invalid for `imshow()` and the error would be different

Comment: Ok I see the issue I think. You are iterating with `range(n_cols)` but you defined `n_columns` You have the variable `n_cols` somewhere in your code and it's value is such that it causes this indexing error.

Comment: .....you are a genius...and I hate myself. haha you are totally right!

Comment: I'm adding an official answer for the sake of completeness

Comment: awesome and I will immediately approve it. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is the result of trying to index the array produced by `plt.subplots()` with a value that is out of the range of the index. One way to show this is by replacing the variables from the loop with just numbers. In this case you will see that `axarr[1,2]` will produce the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-31f90736bd1d> in <module>()
      2 #plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
      3 
----> 4 a[0,2]

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

We know that the error did not occur in the `generate_pattern` function as the error message would have indicated as much.